# Define different heights for head and foot

Tags: fancyhdr, header-footer

is it possible to define different `\headerheight` for head and foot respectively? For example, there is a logo image in the header which needs a large `\headerheight` and only text is in foot which needs a small `\headerheight`. Or does it have two variables to control the heights of foot and head respectively?

Answer (score 22):

if you want to see your page layout with the given values, then print it:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}

\layout

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The height of the header is given by `\headheight` (not `\headerheight`). The distance between the baseline of the header and the top of the page text is then given by `\headersep`.

The height of the footer is defined differently. The dimension `\footskip` states in what distance the baseline of the footer is set to the bottom of the page text. Have a look at the manuals of [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) and [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry), both show a nice drawing explaining all page related dimensions.

If you use `fancyhdr` for your header and footer it tells you automatically which dimension is to small and to what value you have to set it. This can then be done using `geometry`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[head=30pt,foot=<..>]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[c]{\Huge LOGO}
\fancyfoot[c]{Some normal text}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% Disable header and footer rules
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
 Text ...
\end{document}
```

Without the `head=` setting `fancyhdr` showed the following warning:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 30.0pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

Comment: @Martin defining the values for head and foot in geometry does work. thanks. i have another question. how can i know the exact height value, e.g., 30pt in your example? one way is that i don't define \headheight then i get the value from the warning. however, i generate tex source files of calculate sheets from my own program. it is a bundle of files. if i update the height value manually, it will be depressing. i can get the height value by `\settototalheight\headheight{\maxof{\leftheadercalc}{\rightheadercalc}{\midheadercalc}}`. so how can i set this value to head in geometry?

Comment: @Martin due to character limit, i have to split my comment into two pieces. in above comment, `\leftheadercalc`, `\rightheadercalc`, `\midheadercalc` are newcommand definition of the real content of head. in tex, how to set value to a variable especially it is in preamble.

Comment: @warem: Funny `geometry` should work. However AFAIK it stoes sets the `head=` value in `\headheight` and `foot=` in `\footskip`. Check its manual again for the details.

Comment: @Martin what is the meaning of "AFAIK"? on the other hand, i found i had made a concept mistake. the foot height is controlled by `footskip`.:(

Comment: @waren: AFAIK = As Far As I Know; and IMHO = In My Humble Opinion. And I state that the footer height is controlled by `\footskip` in my answer.

Comment: @Martin `\footskip` means the distance from the bottom of the last line of text in the body to the bottom of the footer. it doesn't control footer height. there is `\footheight` in LaTeX2.09 but it doesn't exist in current release. so how to define footer height now?

Comment: Yes @warem, that is what I wrote in my answer: "The dimension `\footskip` states in what distance the baseline of the footer is set to the bottom of the page text." There is no direct dimension which controls the foot height. You need to set `\footskip` to a large enough number and reduce `\textheight` appropriately.

Comment: @Martin it seemed that there is no way to get correct `\footskip` by tex itself. then i have to update the values for my bundle of files manually.:(

Comment: @warem: If you want to set the `\footskip` automatically then you should have asked this as part of your question. Maybe you should open a new one asking about this.

Comment: @Martin i tried to set `\footskip` automatically today and found that it can be set a correct value by using the method i mentioned in my above comment, say, `\settototalheight\footskip{\maxof{\leftfootercalc}{\rightfootercalc}{\midfootercalc}}` where `\leftfootercalc`, `\rightfootercalc`, `\midfootercalc` are newcommand definition of the real content of footer. this didn't work yesterday due to other errors. for a newbie, misunderstanding some concept could lead to unpredictable errors. anyway, thanks a lot.