# Changing text area for Table of Contents in Koma Script

Tags: table-of-contents, margins, koma-script, geometry

My friend is just about to submit her Diplomarbeit (German M.Sc.) and she bumped into a tiny corner of Koma-Script. The Table of Contents was just a tiny bit too long. Thus, one chapter was forced into a new page, which seemed quite ridiculous.

[image: Toc Broken]

She tried solving the problem on her own by using the `geometry` package, but that didn't work out (I didn't see her solution). So she called me for help. 
I knew she was using Koma, and I searched a bit, [and bumped into the nice package called `layouts.`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10896/define-different-heights-for-head-and-foot). 
So the question was: how do we change the height for the table of contents in the Koma package?
Or more generally: how to control page geometry in the Koma package, when the Geometry package will not help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try saying

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\enlargethispage*{1\baselineskip}}%
}
```

just before `\begin{document}`.

If this is not sufficient, try with 2 instead of 1. Remember that two runs of LaTeX are necessary for such adjustments to be processed completely when a change is made.

You might also want to remove the page number, if it bumps with the line that's been added (this can happen when `2\baselineskip` is needed); in this case say

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\enlargethispage*{2\baselineskip}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}%
}
```

The instruction `\enlargethispage` tells LaTeX to make some more space available in the page. However the footer doesn't change position, so it may interfere with the text; if the table of contents occupies only one page, the missing page number will not be noticed.

Comment: your solution is more complicated than mine, and answer the question: how to fine grain control more properties of the TOC in Koma. I am glad you showed us how! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Well, my solution is no big deal, and could be found in the Koma Manual. However, for a moderate Latex user the answer is not always straight forward, so I decided to post it here:
Section 2.2.4 in the Manual states:

```
2.2.4
Uncommon Type Areas

\areaset[BCOR]{WIDTH }{HEIGHT }
To construct type areas with uncommon proportions or to specify type areas
which have exactly the values of the previous table (without adjusting to an
integer multiple of \baselineskip) it’s also possible to use \areaset 
instead of \typearea. \areaset sets the text width to {WIDTH} and the text 
height to HEIGHT (without any additional corrections) and computes the 
margins in a similar way as the \typearea command...
```

Hence,

```
\areaset{418.25555pt}{620.80026pt}
\tableofcontents
\areaset{418.25555pt}{595.80026pt}
```

Was a solution which allowed "forcing" the Table of Contents into a single page.

[image: Fixed TOC]

I hope this will save some time for new comers to Latex and Koma.