# Fancyhdr header goes on top of main text

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have a problem with headers and footers. When im making header, it goes on the top of my text. Maybe someone can help to fix it.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,LO]{MY TEXT}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}
```

and this is result, which  i get: [image]

I hope it is enough info to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: It's not enough; please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: i dont know if i understood correctly what is MWE, but i tried to put more info in my code. I dont know if thats right

Comment: Click the hyper link in @egreg's comment.

Comment: Looking at your output, I would say that you use more than fancyhdr to produce your document; in particular, the layout of your sections/subsections in not standard. Moreover, still based on the result of your code, I would say that you should play with the different lengths of your page (you can find the different lengths and what are their use in the [fancyhdr documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf), page 3), something is probably wrong regarding the `\textheight`, the `\topmargin` or the `\headheight`.

Comment: I had this issue because I included `\usepackage{fullpage}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the page style to fancy and clean the fancy header with following command:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no line in header area
\fancyhead{}
\chead{your header in center} %\lhead and \rhead also available
```

Comment: There is already a `\pagestyle{fancy}` hidden in is bit of code, and I strongly suspect that what you say won't help since it is more a problem related to the size of the elements of the page than anything else.

Comment: @MBR I had this problem and solve it by this code. I updated with my working copy. place this before `\begin{document}`

Comment: it was very usefull answer, thank yuou. And i have one more question, how to make bigger gap between header line and main text?

Comment: @MindaugasTruklickas I'm glad it could help. For your new question take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85178/increase-height-of-fancyhdr-header and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10896/define-different-heights-for-head-and-foot